# Difficulty Installing Ioncube Loader for PHP 5

Tags: php, ioncube

My PHP version is 5.2.6, my OS is Debian 5.0 x86-64. I am trying to install the Ioncube loader for PHP but I'm having a little trouble with it. What I have done.

- I have downloaded the correct loaders package from here http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
- I have uploaded the **ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so** to my PHP extension_dir so now it's located here: **/usr/lib/php5/20060613/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so**
- I have added this line in my php.ini file: **zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20060613/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so**
- I have checked the php.ini file for any other zend_extension directives but there are none so I just put the **zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20060613/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so** on the bottom of the file.
- I have restarted Apache

After the steps above, I have created phpinfo.php file with this:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

I have loaded the page in my browser and Ioncube is still not enabled. Am I missing something? Did I forget about some important step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that same phpinfo page, what is the Configuration File that it says it's using?  Make sure to update that php.ini as well.

Comment: There was a type in my php.ini file.